# How to edit description of a software using Quickly?

Tags: application-development, quickly

By default descriptions of all new Quickly apps are "UNKNOWN" in the `debian/control` file.
Changing that and releasing a new version does not work (It gets reverted).

How to edit the descriptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the desciption about your program at the bottom in `setup.py`. `setup.py` is located at the main directory of your Quickly project.